# Defined Column name NOT working in simple Macro to Hide Column

Tags: excel, vba

I named a column: `DailyReserveCol`

Created simple Hide/Reveal column button

```
Sheets("Calculator").Columns.DailyReserveCol.Hidden = Not Column.DailyReserveCol.Hidden
```

But I receive the following error:

> Run-time  Error 424 Object Required

This works:

```
Sheets("Calculator").Columns("C").Hidden = Not Columns("C").Hidden
```

I've tried:

```
Columns(DailyReserveCol).Hidden
Columns("DailyReserveCol").Hidden
```

> Error 13   Type mismatch

Am I doing it incorrectly or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to toggle the visibility of a named column:

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("DailyReserveCol").EntireColumn.Hidden = _
       Not Sheets("Calculator").Range("DailyReserveCol").EntireColumn.Hidden
```